# How to write the equation of the tangent plane to the ellipsoid

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Write the equation of the tangent plane to the ellipsoid $\dfrac{x^2}{32} + \dfrac{y^2}{18} + \dfrac{z^2}{5} = 1$ passing through the point $(-12, -3, -1)$ and parallel to the axis $Oz$.

I know that the equation to the ellipsoid in this case looks like this: $\dfrac{x * x_0}{32} + \dfrac{y * y_0}{18} + \dfrac{z * z_0}{5} = 1$.

All planes parallel to axis $Oz$ look like this: $Ax + By + D = 0$.

Answer is: $3x + 4y - 24 = 0$ and $3x - 28y - 120 = 0$. I don't understand why there're two of them and how I can get these equations.

Could somebody please give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint :

In fact, your 3D issue can be reduced to a 2D issue, by  vertical projection onto the x-y plane.

I.e., by taking $z=0$, it is the same as finding the equations of the tangents to the ellipse with equation :

$$\dfrac{x^2}{32} + \dfrac{y^2}{18} = 1$$

issued from exterior point : $$(12,-3)$$.

Here is a graphical representation:

[image]

Is this hint sufficient ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the plane is parallel to $Oz$ , then its unit normal vector is

$ n = (\cos t , \sin t , 0 )$ for some $t$

Let the point of tangency be $r$ then $ r^T Q r = 1 $ , where

$Q = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{32} && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \dfrac{1}{18} && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \dfrac{1}{5} \end{bmatrix} $

The gradient vector which point outward of the ellipsoid and perpendicular to its surface is equal to $ 2 Q r $, since this the direction of the normal to the tangent plane, we have

$ Q r = \alpha n $ for some $\alpha $

This last equation implies that the tangency point $r$ is related to $n$ by

$ r = \alpha Q^{-1} n $

But the tangency point $r$ is on the surface of the ellipsoid, therefore,

$ r^T Q r = 1 $

And this means

$ \alpha^2 n^T Q^{-1} n  = 1 $

So that

$ \alpha = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ n^T Q^{-1} n } } $

And from this, we have

$ r = \dfrac{ Q^{-1} n }{\sqrt{n^T Q^{-1} n } } $

Since the tangency plane passes through $r_1 = [-12, -3, -1]$ , then

$ n^T (r - r_1) = 0 $

Expanding and substituting

$ \sqrt{n^T Q^{-1} n} - n^T r_1 = 0 $

So that

$ (n^T r_1)^2 = n^T Q^{-1} n $

Substituting $n$

$ (-12 \cos t - 3 \sin t ) ^ 2 = 32 \cos^2 t + 18 \sin^2 t $

This reduces to

$ 112 \cos^2 t + 72 \cos t \sin t - 9 \sin^2 t = 0$

Dividing by $\cos^2 t $ yields

$ 9 \tan^2 t - 72 \tan t + 112 = 0$

And this gives two solutions for t:

$ \tan t = \dfrac{1}{18} ( 72 \pm 96 ) = (4 \pm \dfrac{16}{3} ) = \dfrac{28}{3}, - \dfrac{4}{3} $

This means the normal vector is along the directions $(3, 28, 0) $ and $(3, -4, 0) $

The equation of the two plane with these normals are

$ 3 x + 28 y = 3(-12) + 28(-3) = -120 $ or $ 3 x + 28y + 120 = 0 $

and

$ 3 x - 4 y = 3(-12) - 4(-3) = - 24  $  or $ 3 x - 4y + 24 = 0 $

Comment: The person asked for a hint, you are not answering the question asked.

Comment: @Paul I don't see anything wrong in providing a full answer.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without sines and cosines?

Comment: @AmazingDellComputers FYI, what I've usually done in cases where the OP asks for only a hint, but I think it's useful & appropriate to provide a full answer (e.g., for other readers benefit), is to put the portions of the answer that aren't really needed for just a hint behind spoilers, i.e., prefixing the text with ">!".

Comment: @AlisaPetrova Instead of sines and cosines, you can write $n = (n_1, n_2, 0) $